# WPF: Using a "time" textbox to search a database using seconds

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, time, textbox

I have a datatable with a column `Total` which displays total time in seconds.
(Since this can be over 24 hours i used `DateDiff` to calculate the time in seconds, this returns a `INT`) as below:

```
SET tmTotals = DATEDIFF(Second, tmStartTime, tmEndTime)
```

the datatable looks like this:

```
StartTime                 EndTime                   Total
-----------------------------------------------------------        
2018-12-03 00:00:19.257   2018-12-04 00:00:23.288   86404
2018-12-02 10:13:32.586   2018-12-04 10:14:57.298   172885
2018-12-04 12:07:50.636   2018-12-04 18:04:25.526   21395
2018-12-04 03:15:25.061   2018-12-04 13:15:34.665   36009
2018-12-03 20:56:12.947   2018-12-04 03:11:07.992   22495
2018-12-02 00:11:46.020   2018-12-04 00:29:55.051   173889
```

In my WPF application i want to use two `textboxes` to search between two `Total` times in the table. I want these `textboxes` formatted as `hhh:mm:ss` (time can be over 100 hours). How can I get this to an `Int`value so it's usable in the StoredProcedure?

[image: WPF app image: DataTable searching on active time]

With times under 24 hours I used, but this can't be used now:

```
CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(second,  DATEDIFF(second, tmStartTime, tmEndTime), 0), 108)
```

to calculate the total time and in my WPF app I did:

```
<TextBox Name="Activeto" Text="{Binding Path=TotalEnd,  StringFormat= \\hh\\:mm\\:ss }" Width="60"/>
```

and code-behind:

```
TimeSpan timeSpanStart = TimeSpan.Parse(Activefrom.Text);
```

to convert the `string` to a `timespan` which could be used to search between to times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. In the end i simply seperated the time input `textboxes` to three seperate `textboxes` so: `hh` : `mm` : `ss`. In th code-behind i calculated te input to seconds and added them:

```
int TotalBegin = (int.Parse(TotalStarthh.Text) * 3600) + (int.Parse(TotalStartmm.Text) * 60) + (int.Parse(TotalStartss.Text));
int TotalEnd = (int.Parse(TotalEndhh.Text) * 3600) + (int.Parse(TotalEndmm.Text) * 60) + (int.Parse(TotalEndss.Text));
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it works for me!